# How to Programmatically Pass Credentials in an Embedded Power BI Report Server Report

Tags: authentication, iframe, webforms, powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I want to show my Power BI Report Server Reports on a website built using asp.net webforms.

I'm using the IFrame tag.

```
<iframe src = "**report URL**" 
        width = "100%"  height="100%"
        id="ViostreamIframe"
        style="position:absolute; top:0; left: 0"
        autoAuth ="true"
        frameborder="0">
            Sorry your browser does not this types of reports.
</iframe>
```

When trying to reach the page which contains the report, it asks me for credentials in a popup like in the next snapshot.

[image]

I want a secure way to display the report without showing popup to enter a username and password.

**I don't want to pass the username and password through the src in the IFrame**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48688729/setting-up-ssrs-server-with-alternative-to-anonymous-authentication

Answer (score 0):

Passing credentials in Iframe is not possible for some browsers due to security issues. After extensive research, I found two possible solutions:

1. Implement custom authentication and authorization: You can Use below links to implement custom Authentication, But problem is default windows authentication and authorization will not work. So you have to Implement Custom Authentication and authorization.

- https://github.com/Microsoft/Reporting-Services/tree/master/CustomSecuritySample
- https://mirkomaggioni.com/2020/11/28/implementing-custom-authentication-and-authorization-with-power-bi-report-server/
- https://blog.codefarm.me/2021/08/18/powerbi-report-server-with-cas/

2. Use a proxy server: This option requires you to enable basic authentication on report server (both Windows negotiate and Basic Authentication can work together). You can use a proxy server to add your custom logic for verifying the user and add the basic authentication `[Header: Basic (Base64 encoding of "username@password")]` header before hitting the taget Url (actual Power power Bi server).

- load frame with proxy server Url (you can include token as a part of Url for authentication in Proxy Sever)
- Use cookies, so that subsequent request can be authenticated.

You can use the following URL to create a proxy server:

- https://auth0.com/blog/building-a-reverse-proxy-in-dot-net-core/

Note: After implementing a proxy server, you may still encounter some issues. You can resolve them by inspecting the GET and POST requests with headers carefully. Second approach worked for me.

I hope this will help.. Thank you!!

Comment: Santosh, can you help me to implement this? may be we can connect